# Outputing one program audio to two different speakers at the same time

Tags: windows-10, audio, itunes, speakers

I've looked on SE (and the Internet) for a while and cannot find an answer to this.

How do I have one program (iTunes) output its audio stream to two (or more) audio streams at the same time?  I am not looking to have two different programs go to two different speakers.  One of the speakers I am using is connected through HDMI, and the other is DisplayPort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use a software that creates a virtual audio device, one which loops back to both outputs at the same time. This can be done with a few softwares, for example [Virtual Audio Cable](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm). For examples, tutorials like [this](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/virtual-audio-cable-enables-multiple-audio-outputs-in-windows-7/) can show you how to set up a virtual sound card which can then play from multiple devices. There may be a very small overhead on CPU as well as a delay(given that its software based), but these should be miniscule and bearable.

The overall gist is that, instead of Windows piping your audio output to a hardware sound card, it sends it to a virtual card, which then plays the same sound simultaneously from multiple audio devices. As you can imagine, such software can also be used to create sound effects and mirror microphone input to output, to create an echo for e.g.

Comment: Took me a while to read over that poorly worded article you linked, but it worked.  Though, there is a half a second delay.  Thank you!

Comment: I do apologise for the article - it was the first one I found on the topic on Google since I remember using VAC in the past. I don't remember my own one having such a large delay, though it was a few odd years ago. Half a second I think is bearable, for something like music anyway. You're welcome and I'm glad I could help.

Comment: The only thing about this software that isn't good is that it keeps repeating "TRIAL" every six seconds when its in use.

Comment: @Alex I can see how that would definitely be annoying, perhaps there is a similar software you can use? I think there are a number of virtual audio softwares out there, though I've only personally use VAC so I can't vouch for any others unfortunately.

Comment: I also [made a java program](https://pastebin.com/166k1TrX) that does it for me by having it simulate mouse clicks